# How to define periodic functions?

Tags: python, lambda

How can you define a periodic function in python, e.g. the "sawtooth" function?

`f(x) = x`,  for  `–π < x < π` and 2-pi periodically continued on IR

Can you do this with a `lambda` function?

Comment: plz explain `2-pi periodically continued on IR`

Comment: probably would be tricky with a lambda but I'd be tempted to use fmod from the mathmodule

Comment: 2-pi periodically continued on IR (the set of all real numbers) means f(x) is defined for all real numbers x, and furthermore f(x) is identically equal to f(x + 2pi)

Comment: @AhsanulHaque: I believe "IR" is serving as an ASCII approximation to "ℝ" here.

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.sawtooth.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make use of decorators:

```
def periodically_continued(a, b):
    interval = b - a
    return lambda f: lambda x: f((x - a) % interval + a)

@periodically_continued(-1, 1)
def f(x):
    return x

g = periodically_continued(0, 1)(lambda x: -x)

assert f(2.5) == 0.5
assert g(2.5) == -0.5
```

Comment: +1 Nice idea!  `expense` is an odd word to use, though.  Did you mean `expanse`?  `extent`?  (I'd probably just call it `periodic`, or perhaps `periodic_on`.)

Comment: You also want to replace `x % interval` with `(x - a) % interval`, I think.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thanks for correction. Oh my poor English skill >_<

Comment: oha, now there is a missing ly :D But nice use of decorators!

Answer (score 5):

as a normal function you can use modulo (`%`) also with float:

```
from math import pi

def f(x):
    return (x+pi) % (2*pi) - pi
```

this easily translates to a lambda expression:

```
lambda x: (x+pi) % (2*pi) - pi
```

Comment: You don't need the Python 3 disclaimer: `%` works for floating-point numbers in both Python 2 and Python 3.  And I think you want `(x + pi) % (2*pi) - pi` to get the right result.

Comment: @[Mark Dickinson](http://stackoverflow.com/users/270986/mark-dickinson): you are right. just made a quick plot... thanks & updated.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a function that takes a function and a period, and returns a function:

```
import math

def periodic_function(func, period, offset):
    return lambda x: func( ((x - offset) % period ) + offset )
```

and use that then:

```
sawtooth = periodic_function(lambda x: x, 2*math.pi, math.pi)
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way is to limit the inputs to the first period. Iteratively remove one period until the input falls within the defined values. For example the following example gives a square wave with period 2*pi.

```
def f(t):
    while t>2*np.pi:
            t=t-2*np.pi
    if 0.0 <= t <=np.pi:
        return 1.0
    else:
        return -1.0
```